# VBScript SQL sanitization

Tags: sql, vbscript, sanitization

Wary of Jeff Atwood's "[Bathroom Wall of Code](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001268.html)" post, I thought it would be useful to have a trustworthy SQL sanitisation function for VBScript, similar to PHP's `mysql_real_escape_string()` function.

So, how can I properly sanitise data input into a SQL query using VBScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do it. Use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: +1.  I can think no situation where sanatizing strings can ever be better than using a parameterised SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use the Escape function as below

```
wscript.echo Escape(chrw(1023) & vbtab & vbnewline & " ")
```

which gives

```
%u03FF%09%0D%0A%20
```

. The reverse is UnEscape()